# User.IsInRole false when joined to Azure AD

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, authorization, windows-authentication

I was recently required to re-image a corporate laptop to take a Windows 11 upgrade and to be migrated to Intune / Entra ID (aka Azure AD).  After the re-image, I am finding that User.IsInRole no longer works (returns false incorrectly) in my local dev environment.  The application is an ASP.NET Core Web API with Windows Authentication.  I have confirmed that the required roles (synced from the company's On Premises AD instance) exist in Entra ID, and that I am a member.

The production instance of the application is hosted On Premises, and works fine.  The issue only exists in my local environment on a laptop that is no longer joined to the On Premises AD instance.

Is there something I need to change in the application to allow User.IsInRole to see roles in Azure?  Or is this a Windows Configuration issue?